# Cannot display array of data after login - php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a landing page after a user successfully logs in. The problem is, the user can't display the array of data stored in the DB. I don't have a form. The data was earlier manually inserted into the DB previously. I'm just trying to fetch that data back and display it. I ran:

- `print_r($_SESSION)`
- `error_reporting(E_ALL)`
- `ini_set("display_errors",1)`
- `echo var_dump($_POST)`
- `echo var_dump($_FILES)`

I received only this prompt:

```
Array ( [user_id] => 104 [logged_in] => 1452873569 [id] => ) array(0) { } array(0) { }
```

The user 'id' displayed was correct when I logged in, but the data can't be displayed.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'connect-test.php';
    print_r($_SESSION);

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors",1);

    echo var_dump($_POST);
    echo var_dump($_FILES);

    //declare variables below
    $user = !empty($_POST['id']) ? trim($_POST['id']) : null;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];  
    $color2 = !empty($_POST['country']) ? trim($_POST['country']) : null; 
    $query="SELECT ua.* FROM useradvert ua INNER JOIN users u ON  ua.id =u.id WHERE ua.id='".$id."'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $res2 = $stmt->get_result(); 
while ($row2 = $res2->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
print_r($res2);
            echo "<li>".$_SESSION['nickname'] = $row2['nickname'];
            echo $_SESSION['country'] = $row2['country'];}
?>
```

Comment: is there something wrong with the while loop? etc?please advice.tq

Comment: missing a } in while loop

Comment: can't be displayed HOW? You get a bunch of empty `<li>`? You get no `<li>` at all? And note that your'e buildinng invalid html. you have no container `<ol>` or `<ul>` for your list.

Comment: I hope I'm declaring the variables above correctly. A user will be redirected(via header) to this landing page after a user successfully logs in and suppose to see the arrays of data displayed which is not happening at the moment.

Comment: @Mark Ng, tq...I overlooked. But problem still the same.

Comment: Hi @Marc B. Please bear with me, as I have a limited knowledge. So, u mean,  use <ul> for the opening before <?php in the hmtl. I tried to echo the data in html so I can move the data around easily. However if my method is wrong, please advice me.tq

Comment: @Marc B, i can login. When i run print r session, it display my correct login id. BUt i just can't display the arrays of data..which is nickname and country.any ideas?

Comment: I removed the html, and tried again, still no changes. Can anyone point me to the error? why I cannot display the data after login?

Comment: If you don't have any form $_POST and $_FILES will be empty, please check the result of query by adding `print_r($res2)` below `$res2 = $stmt->get_result();`

Comment: Hi @manRo, Tqs for the reply. I tried that. I got this. It shows empty array. Array ( [user_id] => 104 [logged_in] => 1452873569 [id] => ) array(0) { } array(0) { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why**:

Your $_SESSION contains `[user_id] => 104`, and no value for 'id' ...

Your code tries to extract `$_SESSION['id']` , not $_SESSION['user_id']

Hence your SQL query becomes: `SELECT ua.* FROM useradvert ua INNER JOIN users u ON  ua.id =u.id WHERE ua.id='';`, which most likely doesn't return any rows, and hence the loop isn't executed.

**Debugging**

To see what happens print out the sql statements ... and run them manually agianst your data. If they return nothing, well nothing will be returned to your program either.

**Bonus**:

Well, kinda important as SQL injection is one of the top security mistakes people continue to make ... and make the life of wannabe hackers quite easy.

Prepared statements are meant to separate out code from data, so feeding data into the sql statement is what's to be avoided.

Comment: Hi @swa66..tq for the reply.. u forgot to scroll to the right.. u missed a few characters..  $query="SELECT ua.* FROM useradvert ua INNER JOIN users u ON  ua.id =u.id WHERE ua.id='".$id."'";

Comment: it seems you have a point there. Because in my login page, I have user_id which was staring me all the time. But in my DB, the column in id and not user_id, it seems the problem is coming from the login page. Can I post the login page if it helps? Cause i have a limited knowledge in PHP. tqs in again...

Comment: I've edited my answer above. BUt it seems, the system is still calling user_id. I already changed it in my login page.Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is already logged in you should always get his ID from $_SESSION not $_POST otherwise when someone will send request with valid user id in POST he will get user data without need to login.

So in your case you should only check if user is logged in by checking `$_SESSION`

If you will take a look at your query:

```
$query="SELECT ua.* FROM useradvert ua INNER JOIN users u ON  ua.id =u.id WHERE ua.id='".$id."'";
```

you can see that it's using `$id` variable which is never set before.

You need to ensure that `$id` will be proper user id taken from `$_SESSION`

```
//declare variables below
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
} else {
    //show error
}
```

Besides below lines should be removed as they are not doing anything logical:

```
$user = !empty($_POST['id']) ? trim($_POST['id']) : null;
$_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
```